# Reading string from file and comparing it with another string in other file

Tags: python-2.7

im new in python and looking to do the following 
i have a file that im reading from

```
   searchfile = open('filename','r')

   for line in searchfile:   
       if 'specificWord' in line:

       print line

   searchfile.close()
```

now i cant find a way to compare `specificWord` with another `specificWord` at 
a different file.
and print the line of thet `specificWord` to the screen.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file_open:
    lines = file_open.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'specific_word' in line:
            print line
```